# Convert first element of each sublist to float

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning and I want to find more efficient or elegant (shorter) way to do the same:

```py
list1 = [['-0.02', 'AAA'], ['-0.20', 'BBB'], ['0.10', 'CCC'], ['0.05', 'DDD']]


def convert_first_element_to_float(lst):
    ls_a = []
    ls_b = []
    for el_a, el_b in lst:
        ls_a.append(float(el_a))
        ls_b.append(el_b)
    return [list(a) for a in zip(ls_a, ls_b)]


result = convert_first_element_to_float(list1)
```

and result is:

```
[[-0.02, 'AAA'], [-0.2, 'BBB'], [0.1, 'CCC'], [0.05, 'DDD']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) might qualify as a more elegant way:

```
>>> result = [[float(i), j] for i, j in list1]
>>> result
[[-0.02, 'AAA'], [-0.2, 'BBB'], [0.1, 'CCC'], [0.05, 'DDD']]
```

While it is [operationally very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907109/python-list-comprehension-vs-for), it may lead to a very slight performance improvement and usually is more concise as far as lines of code is concerned.

The `for i, j` part unpacks each pair of elements from each sublist in `list1`.