# Optimizing code for calculating a financial bond's price

Tags: python, finance

As I'm new to programming, I was wondering whether a function I made to calculate a financial bond's 
fair value could be optimized.

What I made goes as follows:

```
def bondPrice(FV, coupon, r, yld, t):
        disc_value = 0
        for i in list(range(round(t)+1)):
            cf = (FV*coupon/pmts)/(1+yld/pmts)**(i+1)
            disc_value += cf
        disc_value += FV/(1+yld/pmts)**(i+1)
        return disc_value
```

Which given the inputs:

```
 r=.05 # 6-month and 1-year zero rates
 t=1.5 # bond's maturity in years
 coupon=.04 # bond's coupon
 yld=.052 # yield per annum
 pmts = 2 # number of payments per year
 FV = 100 # face value
```

Returns around 98.2897 (if rounded to 4 decimals).

Any other tips or suggestions you think are relevant after reading this are welcome too :)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [Present Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value) which is easily calculated without loops.

Comment: @MarkRansom how could I do it without the loop, but still account for the different years when discounting the coupons?

Comment: On the quant finance side ... do you think your current loop over `t` correctly captures the **number of coupons** that will occur in that time?  Do you think you’ve correctly captured the maturity time for discounting the principal using `i + 1`?

Comment: You can calculate the sum of your geometric series and just implement that in 1 line instead of a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension, they are much faster:

```
def bondPriceLC(FV, coupon, r, yld, t): 
    disc_value += FV/(1+yld/pmts)**(i+1) + [ sum((FV*coupon/pmts)/(1+yld/pmts)**(i+1)) for i in list(range(round(t)+1)) ] 
    return disc_value
```

Here's a related [answer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907109/python-list-comprehension-vs-for/16907417&ved=2ahUKEwjXsIm78KHmAhWBslkKHbYiAlsQFjABegQICRAU&usg=AOvVaw0qFal92TYkKioists6EgJN)

Comment: You might want to `sum` the list comprehension for coupons (which is wrong btw, because the original loop code is wrong)

Comment: I am ignorant to quant finance so please feel free to point out any errors. By the way is there an analytic solution to this equation?