# is there another way to write this code?this seems pretty hard to understand

Tags: python, for-loop, opencv

I saw this on an OpenCV course on youtube and I didn't get it.
can someone explain what is this and is there any easier way to write this part?

```
import cv2
event = [i for i in dir(cv2) if 'EVENT' in i]
```

Comment: You might want to read this [SO post on list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16907109/6692898)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called [`list comprehenstion`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's similar to

```py
import cv2

event = []
for i in dir(cv2):
    if 'EVENT' in i:
        event.append(i)
```

The [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is used to get all valid attributes from `cv2`, then if the current attribute (`i`) has an `EVENT` on its name then that would be stored on `event`.

The code below will print `['EVENT_1', 'EVENT_3']`.

```py
class CV2:
  EVENT_1 = 1
  two = 2

  def EVENT_3():
    return 3

cv2 = CV2()
print([i for i in dir(cv2) if 'EVENT' in i])
```

Comment: what is the first i for ?

Comment: It's referencing the current item on the `for loop`.

Comment: dir() works differently for different cases, mostly gives back the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The `dir` command is a built-in command in Python ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)) and is used to list all the attributes on the object.

So this command is looping through all the attributes in cv2 and filtering those that have 'EVENT' in the name.

To make this more expressive, I would list out the EVENT attributes you are interested in