# How do I create a new list with a nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of words

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
```

and I want to end up with a list of letters (not including any repeated letters), like this:

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

without a list comprehension the code would like this:

```
letter_list=[]

for a_word in word_list:
    for a_letter in a_word:
        if a_letter not in letter_list:
            letter_list.append(a_letter)
print(letter_list)
```

is there a way to do this with a list comprehension?

I have tried

```
letter_list = [a_letter for a_letter in a_word for a_word in word_list]
```

but I get a

```
NameError: name 'a_word' is not defined
```

error. I have see answers for similar problems, but they usually iterate over a nested collection (list or tuple). Is there a way to do this from a non-nested list like a_word?

Trying

```
letter_list = [a_letter for a_letter in [a_word for a_word in word_list]]
```

Results in the initial list: `['cat','dog','rabbit']`

And trying

```
letter_list = [[a_letter for a_letter in a_word] for a_word in word_list]
```

Results in:`[['c', 'a', 't'], ['d', 'o', 'g'], ['r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']]`, which is closer to what I want except it's nested lists. Is there a way to do this and have just the letters be in letter_list?

Comment: `letter_list = [a_letter for a_word in word_list for a_letter in a_word]`?

Comment: If splitting into characters is all you need, then you can use `list("".join(word_list))` instead of list comprehension.

Comment: oh wow, this seems so simple now! i am having a hard time following the logic a little bit, but thanks! is there a way to add a conditional so that only letters that aren't in the list already are added? I can't use "if not in letter_list" since I am just defining that variable no?

Comment: In modern Python (CPython and PyPy 3.6+, 3.7+ as a language guarantee), `dict`s are insertion-ordered, so you can accomplish this efficiently with `list(dict.fromkeys(''.join(word_list)))`. Or replace `''.join(word_list)` with `itertools.chain.from_iterable(word_list)` if you don't want to make the larger temporary string (though the string is likely faster). The `dict` will only keep the first appearance of any character, omitting the rest.

Comment: I updated my answer. PLease take a look

Answer (score 2):

**Update.** How about this:

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
new_list = [letter for letter in ''.join(word_list)]
new_list = sorted(set(new_list), key=new_list.index)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Comment: it will not remove repeating characters from list

Answer (score 1):

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = list(set([letter for word in word_list for letter in word]))
```

This works and removes the duplicate letters, but the order is not preserved.  If you want to keep the order you can do this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys("".join(word_list)))
```

Comment: oh this might be the easiest solution, actually. perhaps I can do a sort on the set? it's a small question in a textbook i am working thru and it's a review of python so I am not sure what the answer they're expecting is.

Comment: actually, I just realized this would only give me alphabetical order, so this is probably not the solution expected. I am curious to know if it's possible to do with with an if statement.

Comment: yes, i added an edit that uses ```OrderedDict``` from the collections module to retain the original order.

Comment: Your second solution is correct (except that you need to change `test` to `word_list`), but the first one will only remove duplicate letters *within* words, not *between* words - there are still two `'a'`s.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using list comprehension

```
l=[j for i in word_list for j in i ]
print(l)
```

output:

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: 100% correct
`letter_list = [char for word in word_list for char in word]`
in clearer code :D

Comment: it is correct. only variable names are changed 
:) :)

Comment: yes, like i said ur answer is correct the code i provided is just more readable :)

Comment: is there a way to make sure that repeated characters aren't included in the list using an if statement?

Comment: @alpablo20, "checking if characters are repated" is not included in your question. Please update your question

Comment: I didn't phrase it quite like that but I did add "(ideally without any repeated letters)." Is there a way to do it with a conditional?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension. It is faster than looping in cases like yours when you call `.append` on each iteration, as explained by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907417/6692898).

But if you want to keep only unique letters (i.e. without repeating any letter), you can use a `set` comprehension by changing the braces `[]` to curly braces `{}` as in

```
letter_set = {letter for letter in word for word in word_list}
```

This way you avoid checking the partial list on every iteration to see if the letter is already part of the set. Instead you make use of pythons embedded *hashing* algorithms and make your code a lot faster.

Comment: is it possible to do it with a conditional at all? I was hoping to find a way to do that if possible, but obviously i can't check whether that item is in the current list since it is just being defined, so I am not sure how else to do it with a conditional.

Comment: What do you mean by "a conditional"? The fact that it is a set (not a list) comprehension will remove all repeated letters, leaving only one instance of all the letters that appear in all the words, can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> word_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
>>> [c for word in word_list for c in word if (c not in s, s.add(c))[0]]
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

This will test whether the letter is already in the set or not, and it will unconditionally add it to the set (having no effect if it is already present).  The `None` returned from `s.add` is stored in the temporary tuple but otherwise ignored.  The first element of the temporary tuple (that is, the result of the `c not in s`) is used to filter the items.

This relies on the fact that the elements of the temporary tuple are evaluated from left to right.

Could be considered a bit hacky :-)